# Get java.lang.NoSuchMethodError when running simple codes

Tags: java

I have the following JAVA code. It compiles fine, but when I run it, I got the following error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Edge.(LVertex;D)V
    at Test.main(Test.java:27)

Any clue? Thanks in advance!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


class Vertex{
    public int key;
    public ArrayList<Edge> edges;
    public double minDistance = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;

    public Vertex(int key) {
        this.key = key;
        edges = new ArrayList<Edge>();
    }
}

class Edge{
    public Vertex target;
    public double weight;

    public Edge(Vertex t, double w) {
        target = t;
        weight = w;
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Edge e = new Edge(new Vertex(1), 1.0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `.class` files are out of date.

Comment: I'm trying it on my NetBean and it's compiling + running fine.

Comment: You're not posting the offending code/class, Dijkstra.java!

Comment: I am using vim on a mac machine and got the error. I deleted generated  .class files and recompile, but still got the error.

Comment: The error is in the main function where I created an Edge object.

Comment: As Hovercraft said, the error message hints about a file "Djikstra.java". There must be a class called Djikstra in this file, or it would not compile. And this is were the error is happening, not in the code you sent us.

Comment: @Wei: you are wrong. The JVM is telling you that the error is on line 81 of the Dijkstra.java file. I believe what the JVM tells me and so should you.

Comment: It's weird. I compile and run exactly the same file on a linux machine without the running error.

Comment: Why are you still not showing us the Dijkstra.java file? Does it hold state secrets? Is it classified?

Answer (score 1):

If you have deleted all of the .class files and recompiled them all *properly* it is NOT POSSIBLE to get that exception.

The exception is telling you that one class (in this case Dijkstra) is attempting to use a method (in this case a constructor with signature `Edge(Vertex[], double)`) that does not exist in the version of `Edge` that it is loading.

But your source code says that the constructor does exist.  I can see it.

Contradiction!

The only possible explanation I can think of is that there are multiple copies of `Edge.class` floating around, and your launcher's classpath is telling the JVM to use the wrong one; i.e. an old one that you DIDN'T recompile!

---

> It's weird. I compile and run exactly the same file on a linux machine without the running error.

That's easy to explain.  You don't have old/stale copies of the file on your Linux machine.